# Adding Custom Rules using XPath Expressions for Javascript

Tags: javascript, xpath, sonarqube, rule

I would like to add a custom rule for javascript using an xpath expression. This is shown in [sonarqube](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Adding+Custom+Rules+using+XPath+Expressions).

Following problems occur: The mentioned XPath rule template is missing.

My configuration:
SonarQube 5.1
Javascript Plugin 2.5

Regards, Steffen

Comment: Can you show your code? Are you using exactly the code from the link you gave? What XPath rule is mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath rule template [has been removed in version 2.3 of the JavaScript plugin](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJS-314). The [plugin documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JavaScript+Plugin) has already been updated, but the main documentation for XPath rules must be changed.

Comment: Ok. I just thought the feature has been re-integrated in version 2.4 (see: http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/VOTE-Release-SonarQube-JavaScript-Plugin-2-3-td5032191.html).

So, the only possible way to add custom javascript rules is Java?

Do you know a good documentation for that? ...or maybe another way?

Comment: @SteffenHohn you can find an example of how to implement custom rule for JavaScript here: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/javascript-custom-rules